# How to check for git changes to a specific file across all commits in all branches (and non-branches) in local repo ordered by time?

Tags: git

Am trying to establish if a change was erased in a merge by somebody. Suppose the commit is still somewhere in the git commits. Does the following guarantee I will see the change regardless of how it was merged?

```
git log -p --all some_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `git log` overlooks the details of merge commits, you have to add one of the [`--diff-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-mergesoffnoneonfirst-parent1separatemcombinedcdense-combinedcc) option.

In your case `-c` (short for `--diff-merges=combined`) is probably a good fit.

Also : add `--graph`, it really helps in understanding how commits are related.